# Using Meteor Cordova what is the callback function when your app is loaded from the background?

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am created a mobile app using Cordova + Ionic + Meteor.

On iOS users can close the app into the background and go back to it by double tapping the home button.

When the user minimizes the Meteor Cordova application and then brings it back from the background, is there a callback that is called?

My situation is such that when they load the app and if bluetooth is not enabled, it brings you to the settings app where you can enable bluetooth. Then once you navigate back to the app that is in the background, I want to call a function that uses the newly enabled bluetooth hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using [resume callback](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume)?

> The event fires when an application is retrieved from the background.

```
document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Comment: This works. Thank you for pointing this out to me as well as including a link to the documentation!